# Standard ML tutorial code not compiled correctly with SML/NJ

Tags: compilation, sml

I compiled the following code using the command:  `./sml /media/ziqi/storage/sml_code/test.sml` :

```
(* Variables and Declarations *)

type float = real
type count = int and average = real 

type float = real and average = float

val m : int = 3+2 
val pi : real = 3.14 and e : real = 2.17

val x : float = Math.sin pi

val m : int = 3+2 
val n : int = m*m 

val n : real = 2.17


let
    val m : int = 3
    val n : int = m*m
in
    m*n
end

val m : int = 2
val r : int =
    let
    val m : int=3
    val n : int=m*m
    in
    m*n
    end * m

val m : int = 0 
val x : real = Math.sqrt 2.0 
val c : char = #"a"
```

and I got this error report:

```
Standard ML of New Jersey (64-bit) v110.99 [built: Tue Mar 23 10:47:59 2021]
[opening /media/ziqi/storage/sml_code/test.sml]
[autoloading]
[library $SMLNJ-BASIS/basis.cm is stable]
[library $SMLNJ-BASIS/(basis.cm):basis-common.cm is stable]
[autoloading done]
/media/ziqi/storage/sml_code/test.sml:16.5-24.4 Error: operator is not a function [tycon mismatch]
  operator: real
  in expression:
    2.17 let val m : int = 3
    val n : int = m * m in m * n end
```

It is the following code block that caused the failure:

```
let
    val m : int = 3
    val n : int = m*m
in
    m*n
end
```

Then I modified the block causing the issue slightly into a binding statement as follows:

```
(* Variables and Declarations *)

type float = real
type count = int and average = real 

type float = real and average = float

val m : int = 3+2 
val pi : real = 3.14 and e : real = 2.17

val x : float = Math.sin pi

val m : int = 3+2 
val n : int = m*m 

val n : real = 2.17

val h : int = 
    let
        val m : int = 3
        val n : int = m*m
    in
        m*n
    end

val m : int = 2
val r : int =
    let
    val m : int=3
    val n : int=m*m
    in
    m*n
    end * m

val m : int = 0 
val x : real = Math.sqrt 2.0 
val c : char = #"a"
```

To emphasize, the only difference is that the "let" block causing the issue was modified into the following binding statement:

```
val h : int = 
    let
        val m : int = 3
        val n : int = m*m
    in
        m*n
    end
```

and the code was compiled and run successfully with the following result:

```
Standard ML of New Jersey (64-bit) v110.99 [built: Tue Mar 23 10:47:59 2021]
[opening /media/ziqi/storage/sml_code/test.sml]
[autoloading]
[library $SMLNJ-BASIS/basis.cm is stable]
[library $SMLNJ-BASIS/(basis.cm):basis-common.cm is stable]
[autoloading done]
type float = real
type count = int
type average = float
type float = real
type average = float
val m = <hidden> : int
val pi = 3.14 : real
val e = 2.17 : real
val x = <hidden> : float
val m = <hidden> : int
val n = <hidden> : int
val n = 2.17 : real
val h = 27 : int
val m = <hidden> : int
val r = 54 : int
val m = 0 : int
val x = 1.41421356237 : real
val c = #"a" : char
```

It seems that the compiler did not like a "let" expression without being bound to a variable in this case. But compiling the "let" express alone was successful. What is the reason for the failure?

Comment: Terminology notes: Standard ML doesn't have "blocks" (it's a let *expression*) or "statements" (what you call a "binding statement" is called a *declaration*).

Comment: @ruakh Thanks for the correction. I am a newbie learning SML for automated proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that you've (attempted to) put an expression at top level. You can only put declarations at the top level (excepting the REPL-used derived form where `e` is treated as `val it = e`).

Correspondingly

```ml
val n : real = 2.17


let
    val m : int = 3
    val n : int = m*m
in
    m*n
end
```

is parsed as one declaration. As you have two sequential expressions this would be an application expression, to wit, the application of `2.17` to the let expression. As the type error indicates, this is not permitted as `2.17` does not have a function type.

Comment: I guess using ";" at the end of each declaration would pass compilation.

Comment: @ZiqiFan: That's one work-around. Another is to always prefix your expressions with `val ... =`. In cases where you don't actually care about the return value, but only the side-effect, you can write `val _ = ...` and `...` will still be evaluated before its return value is thrown away.